# MS Excel - Can I use SUMIFS to include some criteria and exclude others in just one criteria item?

Tags: excel-formula

Take this table as an example (with "ID" in A1 and the last 55 in D11):

```
ID, Team, Position, Points
1, Blue, Guard, 10
2, Blue, Guard, 15
3, Blue, Forward, 20
4, Blue, Forward, 25
5, Blue, Center, 30
6, Red, Guard, 35
7, Red, Guard, 40
8, Red, Forward, 45
9, Red, Forward, 50
10, Red, Center, 55
```

How can I get the sum of Forwards and non-Centers in one criteria? Ideally, the formula would look something like this: =SUM(SUMIFS(D$2:D$11,$B$2:$B$11,$B14,$C$2:$C$11,$C14))
where B14=* and C14 contains the criteria for Forwards and non-Centers. Ideally, I'd only have one criteria cell, C14. I could add another set of criteria (e.g., =SUM(SUMIFS(D$2:D$11,$B$2:$B$11,$B14,$C$2:$C$11,$C14,$C$2:$C$11,$D14))) but the real problem is that sometimes it'll be just one criteria and sometimes it will be more.

I tried using something like ={"Forward", <>"Center"} in C14 but C14 only returned the value of "Forward" (the first item). Any ideas?

Comment: and what is the answer to your question supposed to be?

Comment: are you trying to double count forwards?  ie once for the forward criteria and then again as part of the non center criteria?.  or if you only need to count them once, then the forward part is a mute point since they will be covered by non-center?

Comment: @Forward Ed Ah, good question! The answer I'm looking for is basically the sum of non-Centers (i.e., sum of all points except for IDs 5 and 10). I don't want to double count any of the points.

Comment: @ForwardEd Yea, this example may not be the greatest. Just imagine if there were 100 other positions and a bunch of other criteria (e.g., sum of all points from players that played on a Tuesday, without scoring more than 30 points, who are between ages 20 and 25, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put you criteria in a table using **Format as table** in the **Home** tab, then in the formula put the table range where is your criteria it will appear something like:  `TableName[FieldName]`

`{=SUM(SUMIFS(D2:D11,C2:C11,Table1[Criteria]))}`

Activate the formula as an array using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Now you can add and delete all the criteria that you want for the formula.

[image]

Comment: I tried that and the criteria array, {=A1:A2}, only returns the first value in the array so the SUM doesn't work as intended. Editing the formula directly like that might be the only option but it's not really what I was hoping for. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you could use a SUMPRODUCT.  It will perform array like operations without actually being an array.  The concept with be based on things matching your criteria as being true, which in a math operation becomes 1, and things that do not match your criteria as being false or 0 in a math operation.

Lets make 4 ranges

```
ID = $A$2:$A$11
TEAM = $B$2:$B$11
POSITION = $C$2:$C$11
POINTS = $D$2:$D$11

=sumproduct((POSITION<>"Center")*POINTS)
```

when you break this formula down, what it will do first is generate an array of true false results.  In your case it will be something like this:

```
(TRUE)*10
(TRUE)*15
(TRUE)*20
(TRUE)*25
(FALSE)*30
(TRUE)*35
(TRUE)*40
(TRUE)*45
(TRUE)*50
(FALSE)*55
```

It will then turn all the true false into 1 or 0 to do the math operation so it will look like this:

```
(1)*10
(1)*15
(1)*20
(1)*25
(0)*30
(1)*35
(1)*40
(1)*45
(1)*50
(0)*55
```

It will then perform the math operation of giving you a list of numbers that meet your requirement and a value of zero in the spot where your requirement was not met.  The very last step of the SUMPRODUCT formula is to sum all numbers in the list.

in this case you get 240  The number of points by non centers.

Now in the case where you have multiple criteria * will act like an AND operator in a logical statement.  So if you want to know the points for TEAM is RED, and Guard position  your formula would become:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TEAM="Red")*(POSITION="Guard")*POINTS)
```

Which would give you 75

Now since SUMPRODUCT performs array like operations, avoid using full column references as you can cause excessive calculations.  Also while it works really nice and tidy in a single cell operation, try not to repeat the formula too often.  You will know when you do as it will take longer for you spreadsheet to finish calculating, and potentially crash your prg if you really overdo it.

If you want to do an OR statement use + as you or operator.  So for RED or BLUE TEAM  Center it would look like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((TEAM="Red")+(TEAM="Blue"))*(POSITION="Center")*POINTS)
```

Now one thing to note in there for the OR or rather the +  is that you can't meet more than one of your OR criteria at the same time or you count will go of as you will get 1+1  instead of 1+0 or 0+1.  And axample of where this would fail is all IDs greater than 4 or all ID Less than 7. ID 5 and ID 6 would be true for both cases and you would need to rethink how to do your logic statement or use a different formula or use an array formula.

Comment: thanks for the detailed post! Unfortunately, I don't want to make edits to the formula itself. I just want to edit the single cell that houses the criteria. I do prefer SUMPRODUCT over array formulas so this would be the route to go if entering the criteria in a single cell isn't possible.

Comment: you can replace the words and quotes with cell references